# In $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ the norms induced by inner products are equivalent.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

I need your help to proceed in proving this theorem:

Let $\;\left\|\cdot\right\|_1\;$ and $\;\left\|\cdot\right\|_2\;$ be norms on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ induced by inner products. Then they are equivalent.

But how can I compare two arbitrary inner products in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?
Since what I want to prove is the following:

$$c_{1}\sqrt{(x,x)_{1}}<\sqrt{(x,x)_{2}}<c_{2}\sqrt{(x,x)_{1}}$$

**I was thinking in the use of Gram-Schmidt** but I don't know how can it helps in this.
Can someone help me to prove this theorem?

Thanks a lot in advance .

Comment: Inner products induce norms. The same argument applies.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I don't understand it :(

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a corollary of the fact that all norms on finite dimensional vector spaces (hence all inner product norms) are equivalent. Therefore, as Pedro Tamaroff said, You can just use the proof of that result. See e.g.:

http://www.math.colostate.edu/~yzhou/course/math561_spring2011/norm_equiv.pdf

Comment: Is it matters if we are in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, the thing is that like a fact they say that later on they will prove that any two norms in $R^{n}$ are equivalent. Then what can be done in this case. Thanks

Comment: How can you prove that $p(x)$ has the triangle inequality,and that S is compact? Thanks a lot :).

Answer (score 1):

Pick bases such that one inner product is given by the identity matrix and the other is given by $M$. Since $M$ is symmetric it can be written $M = N^TN$. Now left-multiplication by $N$ is an isometry between the two inner product spaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but can you explain this more please ?

Comment: The thing is, why it should be a symmetric matrix?

Comment: The matrix for a bilinear form is given in terms of a basis ${e_i}$ by the rule $M_{ij} = \langle e_i, e_j \rangle$. Since an inner product is a symmetric bilinear form, we have $\langle e_i, e_j \rangle = \langle e_j, e_i \rangle$, and so the matrix will be a symmetric matrix.

Comment: Ok,but then How you get that the left multiplication by $N$ is an isometry between the inner products?, Can you elaborate more in this please?

Comment: $\langle Nx, Ny \rangle_1 = (Nx)^T (Ny) = x^T M y = \langle x, y \rangle_2 $

Comment: So that computation shows that both norms induced by inner products are equivalents right?